# What defines a "willing target"?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

In context, I'm building a character for a mid-level DnD 3.5 game (actually a replacement for one that was killed) and was considering getting him a Contact Medallion as part of his gear. The item's description says it works "as Rary's Telepathic Bond", and said spell has in its description that it needs a willing target, though the item's description does not give this limitation. In any case, would "willing target" mean I can only use my Medallion to contact teammates from afar, or could I simply use it on anyone within a mile who I am sufficiently familiar with and/or is not actively attacking/hostile to me?

Answer (score 4):

From the [Magic Overview](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#targetorTargets) section, under targets:

> Some spells restrict you to willing targets only. Declaring yourself as a willing target is something that can be done at any time (even if you’re flat-footed or it isn’t your turn). Unconscious creatures are automatically considered willing, but a character who is conscious but immobile or helpless (such as one who is bound, cowering, grappling, paralyzed, pinned, or stunned) is not automatically willing.

I don't have access to the text for that magic item, but [telepathic bond](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/telepathicBond.htm) by itself can't be cast at the sort of distance you're talking about.  Instead, you cast it on several people who are close by, and they can then communicate over a great distance while the spell is active.

I'm not sure how/if the item bypasses this restriction, but the text is likely relevant to your question.

Comment: The text on the Contact Medallion says you can connect with any one creature within one mile known to you.

Comment: @Cobalt the DM will have to decide how that's handled, then; by the RAW I suspect they'd have no way knowing that they needed to designated themselves as willing! I'd suggest just having it work, because otherwise, what's the point of the item?

Comment: @starwed Well, as being unconscious counts as willing, you could use it to contact anybody who's asleep. Admittedly, they're unlikely to be particularly coherent while asleep and will probably count as unwilling if the contact wakes them up, but "I get these recurring dreams where someone's talking to me, but wake up whenever I try to make out what they're saying" sounds like a great plot hook, to me.

Answer (score 3):

The targeting rules of D&D 3 allow you to *try* to use a spell on any target, but the spell fails if the target is invalid.

So you can attempt to contact anyone you want, but if someone resists the intrusion the use will fail. They have to "accept the call," so to speak.

Comment: So it does have to be actively resisted, then?

Comment: It has to be actively allowed, technically.  See starwed's answer for a direct rules quote.  Side note:  the fact you can target sleeping characters and have them count as willing is a little creepy with ranged telepathic bonds...

Comment: Personally, I use the "try and ask" system in any system, even if it has stricter rules. Asking the player who's a target of the spell as simple of a question as "Are you willing?" tends to give them a REALLY tough choice to make. Like getting pulled through a dimensional door because you're holding the hand of the caster as they walk through. No idea where they're going or that they're even casting the spell (with low spellcraft). You won't know what you're agreeing to, but it adds an edge to magic that would otherwise by missing.